# Using InputBox to enter values in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

i have a macro that asks how many new "Plates" (parts) i would like to add. then it inserts new columns based on that value. What i would like to add is a second InputBox asking what part # i want for each. (we use the same # multiple times)

So if it asks how many an and i say 10
Then it asks what part # and i say #1234

Then i would want it to paste 10 new columns each with part #1234.

This is what i have.

```
Dim Answer As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Number As Integer
Dim Plate As String

On Error GoTo whoa
Answer = InputBox("How many new plates would you like add?")
Number = CInt(Answer)
For i = 1 To Number

Plate = InputBox("Enter a Plate number or Press OK")

With sht3
Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Insert
Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 10
sht8.Range("F4:F100").Copy Range("F4:F100")
End With
Range("F8").Value = Plate
Next i
```

Thanks

Comment: I completely agree with @Mat'sMug. Userform is the best way to go for this

Comment: Userforms are pretty cool, though I dislike excel's implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Dim Answer2 as string

 Answer2 = InputBox("FEED ME INPUT")
```

i think you get the gist from here